# Switching views in storyboard after executing code in xcode

Tags: xcode, button, view, storyboard, switch-statement

I made a log-in screen that once you press the button to log-in and it authenticates the user name and password. What I want to do it switch to a different view after the authentication is completed. I am using a storyboard for this application and I have set it up so that the log-in button does a modal seque but it doesn't switch the view. I tested this with a sample button and all it does it switch the view back to the same view and refreshes the view. What do I need to add in order for my function to switch from my ViewController View (the main view) to the next view (RootViewController).
I have a navigationController and an object created from the ViewController class but I don't know how to use them in order to switch views.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I can provide more information or sample code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your question correctly, what you're looking for is [performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a).

In general the [apple documentation on view controllers in storyboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html) is pretty good and covers all of the relavent bits for transitioning between views in storyboards.